# Can one pair multiple audio sources to play simultaneously to a single Bluetooth speaker system

Tags: audio, bluetooth

Not a specific question but a "can you do that" question about bluetooth capabilities. I know that multiple devices can be paired to one speaker set. Is it possible to pair multiple audio stream sources (for instance two laptops) to simultaneously stream audio through one BT speaker or headphone set?

NB: Please read carefully. This specific question has not been posted, though similar have been posted and misinterpreted.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on Windows PC, yes, this is a typical use case for Voicemeeter, virtual audio mixer.